# How to Generate Monthly Cohorts in One Report Using Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

The original table `User`

```
ID   Created_Date   SubmittedAt   ApprovedAt
```

The original table `Campaign`

```
User_ID   Clicked_At
```

Now I want to generate a report with columns like

```
Month  Year  #Applicants  #Submitted  #Approved
```

I wrote queries using postgresql:

```
SELECT To_char(C.clicked_at, 'MON')    AS MON, 
       Extract(year FROM C.clicked_at) AS YYYY, 
       CASE 
         WHEN created_date IS NOT NULL THEN Count(user_id) 
       END AS APPLICANTS, 
       CASE 
         WHEN submittedat IS NOT NULL THEN Count(user_id) 
       END AS SUBMITTED, 
       CASE 
         WHEN approvedat IS NOT NULL THEN Count(user_id) 
       END AS APPROVED 
FROM   campaign C, 
       users U 
WHERE  C.user_id = U.id 
GROUP  BY 1,2
```

I got an error message "`u.created_date` must appear in the `GROUP BY` clause or be used in an aggregate function. However, I just want my results to be grouped by `year` and `month`.

Comment: What is your version of Postgres?

Comment: @KamilG.postgres 3 1.22.1

Answer (score 1):

First, use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  Second, if you want to count the number of non-null values, then you can simplify the code:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(C.CLICKED_AT, 'MON') AS MON,
       EXTRACT(YEAR FROM C.CLICKED_AT) AS YYYY,
       COUNT(CREATED_DATE) AS APPLICANTS,
       COUNT(SUBMITTEDATE) AS SUBMITTED,
       COUNT(APPROVEDAT) AS APPROVED
FROM CAMPAIGN C JOIN
     USERS U
     ON C.USER_ID = U.ID
GROUP BY 1, 2;
```

With this simplification, you no longer have any (explicit) conditional logic at all, so the `group by` clause is fine.

I would suggest that you combine the month and year and sort the results:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(C.CLICKED_AT, 'YYYY-MM') AS yyyymm,
       COUNT(CREATED_DATE) AS APPLICANTS,
       COUNT(SUBMITTEDATE) AS SUBMITTED,
       COUNT(APPROVEDAT) AS APPROVED
FROM CAMPAIGN C JOIN
     USERS U
     ON C.USER_ID = U.ID
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your CASE statements within an aggregate function:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(C.CLICKED_AT,'MON') AS MON,
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM C.CLICKED_AT) AS YYYY,
COUNT(CASE WHEN CREATED_DATE IS NOT NULL THEN USER_ID END) AS APPLICANTS,
COUNT(CASE WHEN SUBMITTEDAT IS NOT NULL THEN USER_ID END) AS SUBMITTED,
COUNT(CASE WHEN APPROVEDAT IS NOT NULL THEN USER_ID END) AS APPROVED
FROM
CAMPAIGN C
JOIN USERS U ON C.USER_ID = U.ID
GROUP BY 1,2
```

Notes:

- if you are using Postgres 9.4+ then you could use [`FILTER`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-expressions.html) clause.
- use explicit `JOIN` clause instead of WHERE clause for connecting tables
- you may be better of with expanding your `TO_CHAR()` to accept year and month

Example:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(C.CLICKED_AT,'YYYY-MM') AS date_year_month,
COUNT(CASE WHEN CREATED_DATE IS NOT NULL THEN USER_ID END) AS APPLICANTS,
COUNT(CASE WHEN SUBMITTEDAT IS NOT NULL THEN USER_ID END) AS SUBMITTED,
COUNT(CASE WHEN APPROVEDAT IS NOT NULL THEN USER_ID END) AS APPROVED
FROM
CAMPAIGN C
JOIN USERS U ON C.USER_ID = U.ID
GROUP BY 1
```